# Vue Draggable view is out of sync with model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable, sortablejs

I am working on some drag + drop functionality and for some reason my view seems to be getting out of sync with my model.  For some of the items in my list I would like them to not be draggable and to remain in their set positions.  When I try to move a draggable item ahead of another one of my non-draggable items is then moved from the position.  I have created a JSFiddle to help explain here https://jsfiddle.net/2tyqjppq/8/.  The use case is moving the value C ahead of B and the order I am expecting is A Z C B but the actual value A B Z C.  I should note that I mean to bind to a computed property and not the model purposely for the case where the drag + drop is invalid it makes it easier to revert.

Data

```
myArray: [
    {'name': 'A'},
    {'name': 'Z'},
    {'name': 'B'},
    {'name': 'C'}
  ]
```

Draggable

```
 <draggable class="warp-div" :list="getElements" :options="{group:'people', draggable:'.element-draggable'}"
@change="onChange">
  <div class="div" :class="[element.name === 'A' || element.name === 'Z' ? '' : 'element-draggable']" :style="'background-color:'+element.color" v-for="element in myArray">{{element.name}}</div>
</draggable>
```

Computed property

```
getElements () {
  console.log('getting list elements');
  console.log(this.myArray);
  const temp = this.myArray.map(t => t);
  return temp;
}
```

Method for updating model

```
onChange (event) {
    if (event.moved) {
    const element = event.moved.element;
    console.log(element.name);

    // +2 to insert into myArray[2] as non draggable items are in spots 0,1
    const indexToInsert = event.moved.newIndex + 2;
    console.log(indexToInsert);

    //remove element from model
    for (let i = 0; i < this.myArray.length; i++) {
        if (this.myArray[i].name === element.name) {
        this.myArray.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    // insert element into proper place
    this.myArray.splice(indexToInsert, 0, element);
    console.log('Finished onChange');
    console.log(this.myArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very weird stuff. I stripped out a lot of stuff, and still get the scrambling behavior. Also, I have the array listed to the console when it changes, and its order is different from what is in the view.
https://jsfiddle.net/2tyqjppq/9/

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could come to achieving this is to cancel the move (Ref: [How to cancel a drag](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/45)).

This doesn't give you exactly the same UX, since the non-draggable elements do begin to drag, but they do not complete the move.

**template**

```html
<draggable class="warp-div" 
  :list="myArray" 
  :options="{group:'alphabet', draggable:'.div'}" 
  :move="onMoveCallback">
```

**component**

```js
methods: {
  onMoveCallback: function(evt, originalEvent) {
    return evt.dragged.classList.contains('element-draggable');
  },
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ay0gs7La/)

---

**Mixed-up indexes**

When the list is partially draggable (i.e only some of the elements have the draggable class), the Sortable internal list is different to the Vue list.

You can see this by tapping in to the `@sort="onSort"` event - the event.oldIndex and event.newIndex reflect positions within the ***sub-list of elements with .element-draggable class***, i.e items 'B' and 'C'.

The `@change="onChange"` method receives the Vue version of oldIndex but the Sortable version of newIndex. The display is updated before **onChange** runs (see the $emit is in $nextTick), so using this hook does not look viable.

**vuedraggable.js**

```js
onDragUpdate(evt) {
  removeNode(evt.item)
  insertNodeAt(evt.from, evt.item, evt.oldIndex)
  const oldIndex = this.context.index
  const newIndex = this.getVmIndex(evt.newIndex)
  this.updatePosition(oldIndex, newIndex)
  const moved = { element: this.context.element, oldIndex, newIndex }
  this.emitChanges({ moved })
},

...

emitChanges(evt) {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$emit('change', evt)
  });
},
```

Comment: So, how to work around the "mixed-up indexes" problem?